# Data-binded Text is not shown in my UI5-Application

Tags: sapui5

I want to bind text from my JSON-Model to the text of a button.

My controller initializes my model:

```
onInit: function () {

            var oModel = new JSONModel({
                "test": "Hello"
            });

            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "jsonFile");

        }
```

My View looks like this:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.Home">
   <Page id="_IDEGen_page0" title="{i18n>homePageTitle}" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
      <content>
         <Button id="_IDEGen_button0" text="Start new Game" press="onPressStartGame"/>
         <Button text="{jsonFile>test}"/>
      </content>
   </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

But when I run my application, the ui5-inspector show my that the binding is active, but the text is not shown.
[image: Running Application with model binding]

I have no idea, what the problem could be in this case. Who can help me? What could be the problem, that the text is not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the slash in your binding

`<Button text="{jsonFile>/test}"/>`